# How to add independent buttons at the end of each data row in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm getting data from a back-end through an AJAX GET method, and presenting it in a list(below) in html. I tried to put the button tag in there and I get the buttons on the list but I'm not sure how to use the delegate and others to make it work.

So how can I put independent buttons that send the users to a details page about the cafeteria in that list? (This is just a personal project)

```
$(function(){

    var $cafeterias = $('#cafeterias');
    var $Name = $('#CName');
    var $Location = $('#CLocation');


    function DispCafeteria(cafeteria) {
      $cafeterias.append('<li> Name: '+cafeteria.Name+'Location: '+cafeteria.Location+'<button id="Details">Details</button>'+'</li>');
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'some url',
        success: function (cafeterias) {
              $.each (cafeterias, function (i, cafeteria){
                DispCafeteria(cafeteria);
              });
        },
        error: function() {
          alert('Error while loading cafeterias');
        }

      }); 
});
```

Comment: How do you actually want it to work? You should likely add a unique id, for example the CafeteriaID to the button so it'll be unique. Also, how would you like the button to work? Will it also trigger an onClick event that will then transfer you to the Details page?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your comment correctly, I've already tried to insert the id to the button, and yes it will also trigger an onClick event that will transfer the user to the details

Comment: I think @Sukima's answer already shows what you want.

Comment: yes it does it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few nit pick:

- Don't name functions with a leading capital letter unless your planning to instantiate it (constructor function). It confuses people since this is the common de facto standard.
- Avoid nested callback logic. Use a promise interface instead. (jQuery has one).
- Don't construct interactive DOM elements with HTML strings. It makes it difficult to attach events to it. An exception is using event delegation which in your example is a better more performant way to do that.

You should break your problem space down. Separate concerns into smaller chunks.

Fetch AJAX Data:

```
function fetchData() {
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'some url'
  });
}
```

Handle errors:

```
function handleErrors(err) {
  alert('Error while loading cafeterias');
}
```

Construct the DOM:

```
function cafeteriaToString(cafeteria) {
  return 'Name: ' + cafeteria.name +
    ' Location: ' + cafeteria.location;
}

function constructDataTable(cafeterias) {
  $.each(cafeterias, function (i, cafeteria) {
    var $button = $('<button/>')
      .text('Details')
      .data('details-id', i);
    $('<li/>')
      .text(cafeteriaToString(cafeteria))
      .append($button);
  });
}
```

Attach a delegated event:

```
function handleButtonClicks(e) {
  var detailsId = $(this).data('details-id');
  // Do something with detailsId
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
function init() {
  fetchData()
    .then(constructDataTable)
    .fail(handleErrors);

  $('ul').on('click', 'li>button', handleButtonClicks);
}
```